# Ansible always fails at 22nd line in requirements.yml file

Tags: ansible

I run the following command: `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml --force -vvv`

This is my requirements.yml file:

```
---
- src: andrewrothstein.hub
- src: geerlingguy.adminer
- src: geerlingguy.apache
- src: geerlingguy.certbot
- src: geerlingguy.composer
- src: geerlingguy.docker
- src: geerlingguy.drush
- src: geerlingguy.git
- src: geerlingguy.java
- src: geerlingguy.jenkins
- src: geerlingguy.memcached
- src: geerlingguy.munin
- src: geerlingguy.nginx
- src: geerlingguy.mysql
- src: geerlingguy.nodejs
- src: geerlingguy.php
- src: geerlingguy.php-mysql
- src: geerlingguy.php-versions
- src: geerlingguy.pip
- src: geerlingguy.postfix
- src: geerlingguy.ruby
- src: geerlingguy.solr
- src: idealista.consul-role
- src: kibatic.traefik
- src: oefenweb.swapfile
- src: sbaerlocher.wp-cli
- src: wtanaka.jq
```

Whatever is on the 22 line (in this case ruby), it fails with:

```
- downloading role 'ruby', owned by geerlingguy
https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v1/roles/?owner__username=geerlingguy&name=ruby
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: Failed to connect to galaxy.ansible.com at port 443: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy", line 118, in <module>
    exit_code = cli.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 162, in run
    self.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 156, in execute
    fn()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 398, in execute_install
    installed = role.install()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/role.py", line 210, in install
    role_data = api.lookup_role_by_name(self.src)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/api.py", line 56, in wrapped
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/api.py", line 193, in lookup_role_by_name
    data = self.__call_galaxy(url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/api.py", line 56, in wrapped
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/api.py", line 93, in __call_galaxy
    timeout=20)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 1162, in open_url
    client_cert=client_cert, client_key=client_key, cookies=cookies)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 1070, in open
    r = urllib_request.urlopen(*urlopen_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 781, in http_request
    raise ConnectionError('Failed to connect to %s at port %s: %s' % (self.hostname, self.port, to_native(e)))
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to galaxy.ansible.com at port 443: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

If I swap `geerlingguy.git` with `geerlingguy.ruby`, the ruby item downloads correctly but now git gives the same error.

```
Ansible: 2.7.13
PIP: pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

I'm pretty sure this worked at some point. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I tried in my everyday install (Ansible 2.8.4 running under python 3.6) and in a virtualenv with your exact same version of ansible and python: absolutely no problem. Did you try to download in a brand new empty dir (`-p path/to/roledir`) to see if it fixes the problem ?

Comment: I just tried to an empty directory as you suggested and I have the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you have all the other roles (before line 22) already downloaded. Line 22 is the first one where galaxy.ansible.com is being contacted.

Comment: Check if the machine where you are running the ansible-galaxy command can resolve the DNS for galaxy.ansible.com

Comment: The way I'm going around this is running the install command and then moving the ones that fail and below to the top.  (Kind of an odd issue.  It seems like it is timing out or something and then can't find galaxy.ansible).  I did ping galaxy.ansible and everything seems fine.

Comment: One time I remember hitting a similar issue when installing a large number or roles in one requirements file, and I found out after discussing on Ansible IRC that it may have been some sort of CDN rate limiting with galaxy.ansible.com

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking that is the issue.